# SIGSEGV when using nested derived data types with allocatable components

Tags: fortran, derived-types

I have two Fortran derived data types and one of them is nested like

```
type particle
  real :: x
  real :: v
end type particle

type species
  real :: m
  real :: q
  type(particle), allocatable, dimension(:) :: p
end type species

type(species) :: sp
```

Now suppose, I define another real array `z(1:20)` and allocate my derived data type `species` with `allocate(sp%p(1:20))` so that the dimension of `z` and the array `p` matches.

Now the statements (after proper initialization, of course)

```
z = sp%p%x
```

and the one

```
z(1:20) = sp%p(1:20)%x
```

compile with no errors by `gfortran`. But while the former one is OK at runtime, the second one produces a `SIGSEGV` error. Can anyone please point out if I am doing anything obviously wrong?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Your code is actually Fortran 2003 anyway, because of the allocatable component.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. It is necessary.

Comment: I sencond that: please provide an example that yelds the error, because I just did a test with gfortran 8.0.0 and got no errors.